# ffmpeg: PNGs to side-to-side (RGB and Alpha) video

Tags: ffmpeg, png, alpha

I have a set of PNGs and would like to split RGB and Alpha channels of images and then make side-to-side video of them. I understand that filter is what I need but it's really complicated for me. I took a look on [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260930/ffmpeg-splitting-rgb-and-alpha-channels-using-filter), but didn't get a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i item%4d.png -vf "split [a], pad=iw*2:ih [b], [a] alphaextract, [b] overlay=w" -q 1 -r 24 -y out.webm
```