# Converting alpha channel of PNG sequence to Y channel of H265

Tags: ffmpeg, yuv

I have a video renderer that expects two H265 streams (YUV420) and I need to bake them to have one of them form an alpha mask to the other one. This is all solved and works well, however if I follow the instructions here:
[ffmpeg splitting RGB and Alpha channels using filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260930/ffmpeg-splitting-rgb-and-alpha-channels-using-filter)
the alpha channel is slighly off. My hypothesis is that this is due to the alpha channel being scaled through the RGB->YUV matrix.

The input is a sequence of PNG files, the output is two MKV files.

The question is then: How can I tell FFmpeg to “reinterpret” the alpha channel as the Y channel without touching the pixel data? Ideally by producing both MKV:s in one command line as shown in the other question, but at least without rewriting the source files.

Comment: Share your full command.

Comment: @Mulvya. I’ll try to find a minimal example that shows my problem, but currrently I use the exact same filter from the thread I referred to. The only thing different is that my input is %d.png, my output is .mkv and the codec is h265.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the rawvideo format with pixelformat yuv444p and a small script to write the rawvideo input (basically writing the alpha channel to the Y channel and zeros everywhere else).

If there is a cleaner solution (i.e. one that does not require piping through a custom script), I will happily accept that as the answer :)

Comment: Here is a complete solution with a command line utility that splits Animation video into 2 videos: https://github.com/mdejong/AlphaOverVideo